# PHP: generate key table based on 2 SQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

### 1. Set Up

Following **SQL tables** are given:

```
$rooms = 'CREATE TABLE rooms (
room_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL auto_increment,
name VARCHAR(1000)
)';

$types = 'CREATE TABLE types (
type_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL auto_increment,
name VARCHAR(1000)
)';

$seo_data = 'CREATE TABLE seo_data (
seo_data_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL auto_increment,
room_id INTEGER,
type_id INTEGER,
name VARCHAR(1000)
)';
```

I have some rooms like **kitchen** and **livingroom** and some types like **curtain** and **pleating**.

### 2. Problem/Question

How to combine each room with each type and generate a unique **seo_data_id**.
I tried to query the rooms and types table and loop through them.

```
$rooms = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM rooms');
$rooms->execute();
$res_r = $rooms->fetchAll();

$types = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM types');
$types->execute();
$res_t = $types->fetchAll();

for ($i=0; $i < count($res_t); $i++) {
 for ($i=0; $i < count($res_r); $i++) {
  echo $res_t[$i]["name"] . $res_r[$i]["name"];
}
}
```

But this **is not working**.

Comment: If you map both table data in `seo_data` then why you did not try to do it with MYSQL JOINS.???If table room has 3 rows and table types have 5 rows it creates problem.

Comment: can u explain again what u wanna achieve m lil lost

Comment: create categories like /curtains/livingroom with a product grid and an individual category title, meta description and seo text.